# What are the exact dimensional restrictions of MIP mapped textures?

Tags: opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

The OpenGL Es 2.0 Programming Guide (Munshi et al., 2008) says the dimensions must be a power of two (unless the driver supports the extension "GL_OES_texture_npot", which allows non-power-of-two textures to be MIP mapped).
But Is it safe to assume, that MIP mapped textures don't have to be *quadratic* as well, i.e. dimensions such as 1024x512 are allowed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is also my understanding that such dimensions are allowed.

I'd just like to point out that the POT vs NPOT dimensions is an issue different to square vs non-square.